# Why is the change event fired on blur of a controlValueAccessor

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, angular-forms

If I put a custom input implementing the ControlValueAccessor interface in my template and bind to its change event like this:

```
  <input-app [value]="'initialVal'" (change)="onChange($event)"></input-app>
```

With my custom input not firing any event on blur ( to be clear you have to focus on the input, change it, then blur, the event will then appear in the console).

```
<input
    type="text"
    [value]="value"/>
```

The `onChange()` method will be called and I don't understand why exactly that is the case.

[Here is a plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/SNBedFpfEfnP9Sqlwr0L?p=preview)

Comment: Your plunker doesn't trigger **onChange()** on blur.

Comment: @Swoox it does check the console. You also have to change what's written in the input but the event fires when you'll blur. I edited my question as this wasn't clear.

Comment: What happens if you console.log in the "onChange" of the **ControlValueAccessor** and remove the function of the component? What is a possibility that happens, is that the abstract class overwrite your function and then triggers it with the onblur event. The event that's sended will stay the same.

Comment: @Swoox sorry I'm not sure I understand your last comment. You mean if I add the (change) to inside the template of the custom input ?

Answer (score 6):

`(change)` should be triggered

> when a change in the input value causes a new value to be committed to
>   the model.

But I don't think you are using a model, in this case.

What you want is to do something each time you type in your input, so I would use `(keyup)` instead.

```
<input-app [value]="'hey'"  placeholder="your name" (keyup)="onChange($event)"></input-app>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit ashamed but the event just bubbles up.

[same with keyup event](https://plnkr.co/edit/upB6CmsnnLRxS74zXgGh):

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div (keyup)="onKeyUp()">
      <input/>
    </div>
  `,
})
export class App {      
  onKeyUp() {
    console.log('it bubbles')
  }
}
```